# How to combine node,express,mongodb with angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I have created App using node,express,mongodb(Building a RESTful API in Node, Express and MongoDB) now i want to add angular front end below is my `server.js` .what can i add in this file . i want to build front(angularjs) end for this application.now if i run node server.js only node server running in 808l port (localhost:8080)I want run both angular and node in same port how can i achieve this help me out?

server.js

```
// BASE SETUP
// =============================================================================

// call the packages we need
var express    = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app        = express();

// configure app
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var port     = process.env.PORT || 8080; // set our port

var mongoose   = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost//:20717'); // connect to our database
var Students     = require('./app/models/students');

// ROUTES FOR OUR API
// =============================================================================

// create our router
var router = express.Router();

// middleware to use for all requests
router.use(function(req, res, next) {
    // do logging
    console.log('Something is happening.');
    next();
});

// test route to make sure everything is working (accessed at GET http://localhost:8080/api)
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.json({ message: 'hooray! welcome to our api!' });   
});


router.route('/students')

    // create a students (accessed at POST http://localhost:8080/students)
    .post(function(req, res) {

        var students = new Students();      // create a new instance of the Students model
        students.name = req.body.name;  // set the students name (comes from the request)

        students.save(function(err) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            res.json({ message: 'Students created!' });
        });


    })

    // get all the students (accessed at GET http://localhost:8080/api/students)
    .get(function(req, res) {
        Students.find(function(err, students) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            res.json(students);
        });
    });



// REGISTER OUR ROUTES -------------------------------
app.use('/api', router);

// START THE SERVER
// =============================================================================
app.listen(port);
console.log('Magic happens on port ' + port);
```

Below is my Folder structure
[image]

Comment: AngularJS does not run on any port. It is not a web server. It is simply a Javascript application and runs solely in the web browser. Node/express need to be instructed to serve static assets such as the index.html, your angular app as a javascript file, and any styles, images, fonts, etc. that a normal web site would have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to install a package called `path`. Then you can put your `index.html` file of your Angular project inside a nested directory as your `server.js`. Let's put it in a directory called `public`, so in your `server.js`, add this line of code:

```
const path = require('path');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

So you can access it directly from your web browser, just accessing  `localhost:8080` (your server URI)

Comment: Okey, so you can add your `angular-project-folder` next your `app` and `node_modules` folders. And use it like I mentionned in my answer

Comment: can u see my question i updated folder structure image there(node,express,mongodb,angular.html)

Comment: Hai i added those two lines and public folder .now i want to know what should i do in 'index.html'

Comment: Your `index.html` should be the entry point of your angular app. In other words, you need to put your anguar app inside the `public` folder. Then you can access your server URI through your web browser (localhost:8080)

Comment: how can i accessing api ?localhost:8080/apiname this will work ??